# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to use this code with those tooltips. In this link: [Code with tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style). In fact I just copied the whole code but it's now working. 
I get an error that says `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function error`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<script>
  $(function() {
    $(document).tooltip({
      position: {
        my: "center bottom-20",
        at: "center top",
        using: function(position, feedback) {
          $(this).css(position);
          $("<div>")
            .addClass("arrow")
            .addClass(feedback.vertical)
            .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
            .appendTo(this);
        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

What is missing here?

Edit:

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
   $('.hasTooltip').tooltip();
});
</script>
```

Using it like this, solved my problem!

Comment: http://jsbin.com/kuteqafele/1/edit?html,output — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why are you loading jQuery ui twice?

Comment: @JuanMendes which you mean?

Comment: @JuanMendes, one is the css and other is the js

Comment: @Sanchit — There were two versions of jQuery UI loaded before the question was edited.

Comment: I still can't reproduce the problem: http://jsbin.com/kicobewiwu/1/edit?html,output

Comment: The example in the https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ site itself doesn't seem to be working also

Comment: @William no it's working , check this https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style

Answer (score -1):

You are including two times the jQuery UI for different versions. This might be causing conflicts. Try removing

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: even i edited my question, still the same problem, any other idea?

Comment: Not my downvote, but guesses like "try this, try that" should be a comment

Answer (score -2):

You are getting the error because jquery-ui is loaded after your script is executed.
you can try to add type="text/javascript" to your scripts normally this must resolve the issue
or you must wait until the script is loaded to execute your tooltip. so you must creat a function that will execute your script after the jquery-ui is loaded.

Comment: "You are getting the error because jquery-ui is loaded after your script is executed" — That isn't what the code in the question shows.