# Bootstrap 5 is not working on laravel project

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have a laravel project and I'm using Bootstrap 5 and the problem is tooltip is not working

I've tried many many ways that people suggested in Stackoverflow but none of them worked for me

Html:

```
<a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="left" title="Home"> <li class="mitem"> <i class="fas fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> </li> </a>
```

JS:

```
require('./bootstrap')
require('../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min')

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-bs-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip();
});
```

Bootstrap version:

```
"bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
```

I even tried without `-bs-` but it didn't work neither

Bootstrap is loaded and everything is working except tooltip

Comment: Hi Alireza, please share what methods have you tried already ?

Comment: Hi Amirali , I have tried most of the methods that people have suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446318/bootstrap-tooltips-not-working

Comment: did you include your javascript tag at the end of your html page?

Comment: did you include latest version of jQuery in your file?

Comment: which javascript you mean? yes jquery is loaded ```import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;```

Comment: I meant the JS code you have added.

Comment: does a normal `console.log()` works?

Comment: Yes it does , but I have this error in console: ```jquery.js?8262:4059 Uncaught TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...)(...).tooltip is not a function```

Comment: the problem is probably from jQuery. look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34290847/uncaught-typeerror-tooltip-is-not-a-function-error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961708/uncaught-typeerror-tooltip-is-not-a-function

Comment: I moved the loading bootstrap.bundle line after loading jquery and it worked but the only problem now is data-placement is not working , tooltip is on top all the time :D